# Best way of signing Android apps on Jenkins using Gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration

I am setting up a Jenkins CI for our Android apps. I'm completely new to Gradle and trying to integrate it nicely with Jenkins. I've installed the Gradle plug-in that runs `assembleRelease` on my apps.

Every possible app built with this CI should use the same keystore to be signed.

What I'v done :

- Create a gradle script for storing alias/password and keystore location :

  ```
  android {
      signingConfigs {
          release {
              storeFile file('/absolute/path/to/keystore')
              storePassword 'XXX'
              keyAlias 'XXX'
              keyPassword 'XXX'
          }
      }

      buildTypes {
          release {
              signingConfig signingConfigs.release
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Then, in every project I have, the build.gradle file contains :

  ```
  if (new File('/path/to/the/build/file/above').exists()) {
      apply from : '/path/to/the/build/file/above'
  }

  buildTypes {
      release {
          **Project-specific config**
      }
  }
  ```

But adding these lines checking if the build is run on Jenkins to every project doesn't seem right.
What I would like is a "parent" or "common" `build.gradle` that will inject this configuration to every project.

How can I do that ?